# oauth 2.0 multiple authentication apis

Tags: facebook, oauth, authorization

I was able to make a google api based Oauth 2.0 authorization module, which seems to work. I had to create an google cloud platform app to get the client id and client secret and register the uris. Now the new requirement is that we need other login options like facebook, stack exchange, etc options.

Now the question is that should I have to register my app with Facebook and stack exchange as well to obtain different client ids and secrets? Is there a generic way ? thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course you have to create apps on the other platforms you want to use as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You could put that as an answer as well, I will accept it. :) Well I was hoping to skip this step in order to make a generic source code some how. But lets see, I will make apps for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the question is that should I have to register my app with Facebook and stack exchange as well to obtain different client ids and secrets?

Yes, of course, you'll have to. An app/client id and secret are integral part of those APIs and their login mechanism. They are not somehow interchangeable between platforms.

Plus, while following the OAuth standard more or less, they all have small difference in their APIs - different endpoints for certain tasks, differently named parameters and permissions, etc. There's a chance that you might be able to re-use code on some level - but you will have to branch out to handle each platform in its own way at some point or other.